# How Interface have accessibility to Object class methods?

Tags: java, interface

I got the below info from Oracle docs:

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

can someone tell me how an interface is able to implicitly declare public abstract methods to each and every public instance methods which are not-final avaliable in Object class ?

```
interface Test {
    public void functionA();
}

class child implements Test{

    public void functionA() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new child();
        test.toString(); // since toString is Objects class method, How it's visible for Test interface ref?
    }
}
```

Comment: Answered as a community wiki, because I'm just guessing as to the meaning of this question ;)

Comment: .... Now I'm not so sure that he's wrong. Voting to re-open. 1+ for the improvement to the question.

Comment: @JonK: please read the edited question.

Comment: @luk2302: please read the edited question. I'm voting to re-open it.

Comment: @sstan: I agree, and I initially voted to close it, but that's the beauty of this site -- you can improve your questions and your answers.

Answer (score 2):

> how an interface is able to implicitly declare public abstract methods to each and every public instance methods which are not-final avaliable in Object class ?

<s>An interface isn't able to do this -- only a concrete object can. My guess is that you're looking at code that shows creation of an anonymous inner class from an interface and think that this is instantiation of the interface -- but it isn't. Rather it's a concrete class, one without a name, that implements the interface, and that *extends from Object*, as all concrete classes do.</s>

---

And now I'm not so sure as this compiles:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void foo();

    @Override
    String toString();

    @Override
    boolean equals(Object o);
}
```

The correct answer may be: because that is how the authors of Java willed it to be.

Answer (score 1):

> How Interface have accessibility to Object class methods?

As always, the answer is in the JLS:

> 4.10.2. Subtyping among Class and Interface Types
>
> > Given a non-generic type declaration C, the *direct supertypes* of the type C are all of the following:
> >
> > - The direct superclass of C (§8.1.4).
> > - The direct superinterfaces of C (§8.1.5).
> > - The type Object, if C is an interface type with no direct superinterfaces (§9.1.3).

So the 3rd point answers your question. As a subtype of `Object`, the interface inherits its methods.

Note: this is true also for generic interfaces (explained in the rest of 4.10.2).